# python: dots in the name of variable in a format string

Tags: python, string-formatting

Say I've got a dictionary with dots in the name of fields, like `{'person.name': 'Joe'}`.  If I wanted to use this in `str.format`, is it possible?

My first instinct was

```
'Name: {person.name}'.format(**{'person.name': 'Joe'})
```

but this would only work if my dict were shaped like

```
{'person':{'name':Joe}}
```

[The relevant manual docs section](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) doesn't mention anyway of escaping the dot.

(Sidenote: I thought that generally

```
def func(**kw): print(kw)
func(**{'a.b': 'Joe'})
```

would cause an error, but the `**`-expanded function call seems to work even if they're **not** valid identifiers!  It *does* error out on non-strings though.  o_O)

Comment: Have you tried escaping the dot with a backslash?

Comment: @RafeKettler: Yes.  That doesn't work because you're escaping it for the string, not the format specifier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a dot in Python format strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035168/how-to-use-a-dot-in-python-format-strings)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
'Name: {0[person.name]}'.format({'person.name': 'Joe'})
```

Comment: Close but that would only work if you're passing a dictionary with a single key, one for each positional replacement. For example this would fail: `'Name: {0[person.name]} Age: {1[person.age]}'.format({'person.name': 'Joe', 'person.age': 42})`

Comment: But you can repeat 0 as many times as is necessary. This works fine: `'Name: {0[person.name]} Age: {0[person.age]}'.format({'person.name': 'Joe', 'person.age': 42})`

Comment: Awesome, I was not aware you could do that and I have learned something. Thanks! :)

Comment: Note that since 2.7 you can omit the integer indices if it's just the same order as in the string: `'Name: {[person.name]}'.format({'person.name': 'Joe'})` yields `'Name: Joe'`. It would still require reusing 0 for subsequent access.  My only problem is that it's kind of ugly.  I guess I could just mangle it to 'person_age' if I needed to make sure.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue and I solved it by inheriting from `string.Formatter`:

```
import string

class MyFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def get_field(self, field_name, args, kwargs):
        return (self.get_value(field_name, args, kwargs), field_name)
```

however you can't use `str.format()` because it's still pointing to old formatter and you need to go like this

```
>>> MyFormatter().vformat("{a.b}", [], {'a.b': 'Success!'})
'Success!'
```

Answer (score 5):

One way to work around this is to use the old `%` formatting (which has not been deprecated yet):

```
>>> print 'Name: %(person.name)s' % {'person.name': 'Joe'}
Name: Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

[f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) handle this cleanly (I realize they were not available at the time of the original post):

```
>>> x = {'person.name': 'Joe'}
>>> print(f"Name: {x['person.name']}")
Name: Joe
```